# Unpacking a tuple in python and iterating over it

Tags: python, tuples, unpack

I'm trying to unpack a co-ord tuple then iterate over it to blit a sprite multiple times:

```
def updateMap(self, playerPosition):

  self.x_coord, self.y_coord = playerPosition 

  t = Tree(self.screen)
  for x in range(self.x_coord):
    for y in range(self.y_coord):
      self.screen.fill((0,104,0))
      t.drawTree((x, y))
```

However I get the following error:

```
File "unnamed.py", line 26, in updateMap
  for x, y in range(self.x_coord), range(self.y_coord):
ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack
```

Grateful if someone can point me in the right direction on the correct way to do this.  Thanks.

EDIT:  I have edited my code to the above to iterate over every coord say if playerPostion is 0,5 so the iteration goes (0,1) (0,2) (0,3) (0,4) (0,5) -- but although I'm not getting any errors it seems the tree does not get drawn correctly. Thanks.. it seems to be the answer, except my coding is just wrong.

Comment: I do not really see tuples, do you want to iterate over every possible combination of *x*,*y*'s?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem ..correct, I was a bit jumpy...I don't see either tuples here, I was just looking at the error message..

Comment: playerPostion is a tuple -- if playerPosition is (0,5) for example I want to draw tree on 0,0   0,1  0,2  0,3 etc

Comment: but `self.x_coord` and `self.y_coord` are always `0` ?

Comment: @IronFist Yeah, I don't know what's up with that?

Comment: May be this expression `playerPosition = self.x_coord, self.y_coord` is the other way around?

Comment: @zzoop .. `range(self.x_coord)` won't do anything if `self.x_coord` is 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want instead:

```
from itertools import product

self.x_coord, self.y_coord = playerPosition #playerPosition is a tuple

t = Tree(self.screen)
for x,y in product(range(self.x_coord+1), range(self.y_coord+1)):
    self.screen.fill((0,104,0))
    t.drawTree((x, y))
```

Comment: Looks to me in that case, one can better determine the minimum since `x` and `y` will always be the same.

Comment: @zzoop...Please consider to accept the answer that helped you the most

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you change:

```
self.x_coord = 0 
self.y_coord = 0 
playerPosition = self.x_coord, self.y_coord
```

to:

```
self.x_coord, self.y_coord = playerPosition
```

then you get the player position x and y in to self.x_coord and self.y_coord

And to iterate over every combination of x and y you either need to put a loop over y range inside inside a loop over the x range

```
for x in range(self.x_coord):
    for y in range(self.y_coord):
        self.screen.fill((0,104,0))
        t.drawTree((x, y))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the OP wants to iterate over the range of X co-ordinates and the range of Y co-ordinates to create a (x,y) for each case.

```
for x in range(self.x_coord):
    for y in range(self.y_coord):
        print(x, y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the built in Python zip function assuming both of the iterables are of the same length. If not then you will need to do a bit of sanitization before to ensure they are.

```
for x, y in zip(range(self.x_coord), range(self.y_coord))
```

Comment: That won't iterate over all the coordinates, though, assuming that's what the question is looking for

Comment: That is not the intended result. OP definitely wants nested iteration.

Comment: This was my best guess about what they were looking for.

Comment: @ColinSchoen .. I was the first to post similar answer to yours but after reading the code carefully, I realized that's not OP intention and deleted my answer ..